# Involutivity of parallel transport equations to imply vanishing curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, curvature, connections

I'm trying to show, using [Frobenius’ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)), that the integrability condition for the parallel transport equations
$$
∂_μX^a + Γ^a{}_{μb}X^b = 0
$$
is the vanishing of the Riemann curvature
$$
R^a{}_{μνb} = ∂_μΓ^a{}_{νb} + Γ^a{}_{μc}Γ^c{}_{νb} - (μ↔︎ν)
.$$
I want to do this using the formulation of Frobenius’ theorem in terms of [tangent distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry)) and involutivity.

---

**What I can do:** It is easiest to use the differential forms formulation of Frobenius’ theorem: *an exterior differential system
$$
ω^a = \mathrm dX^a + Γ^a{}_bX^b
$$
is integrable **iff** the ideal $I = ⟨ω^a⟩$ generated by the one-forms $ω^a$ is closed under exterior differentiation, $\mathrm dI ⊆ I$.*

Observe:
$$
\mathrm dω^a = \mathrm dΓ^a{}_bX^b - Γ^a{}_b ∧ \mathrm dX^b
$$
Since $Γ^a{}_b ∧ ω^b ∈ I$ is in the ideal, we may add this to the two-form above to obtain
$$
\mathrm dω^a \!\!\!\!\mod I ≡ (\mathrm dΓ^a{}_b + Γ^a{}_c∧Γ^c{}_b)X^b
,$$
and therefore $\mathrm dω^a \!\!\mod I ≡ 0 ⟺ \mathrm dω^a ∈ I$ exactly when $F^a{}_b ≔ \mathrm dΓ^a{}_b + Γ^a{}_c∧Γ^c{}_b$ — the ‘Riemann’ curvature — vanishes.
(Is this general to arbitrary vector bundles?)

---

**What I can’t do:** The above is all well and good. However, I want to show the same thing using the “dual” Frobenius theorem formulated in terms of vectors:
*a tangent distribution $Δ$ (a.k.a., a tangent subbundle or plane field) admits an integral manifold at each point **iff** it is involutive, i.e., closed under the Lie bracket, $[Δ, Δ] ⊆ Δ$.*

My attempt at formulating the parallel transport equations in this way goes like this:

Let Greek $μ$ denote coordinates of the base manifold and Latin $a,b$ denote linear coordinates of the vector bundle.
A vector $X$ then has components $(X^μ, X^a)$, where $X^μ$ is the base point and $X^a$ are the vector components.

The tangent subbundle $Δ$ corresponding to the parallel transport equations may be described as
$$
Δ|_X = \{(δX^μ, -Γ^a{}_{μb}X^bδX^μ) \mid ∀ \; δX^μ\}
.$$
That is, if we think of $Δ|_X$ as encoding the “permitted motions” of a point $X$ in the bulk, then the vector components $X^a$ are constrained to move in response to movements of the base point $δX^μ$ according to the equations of parallel transport.

The thing to verify now is that, given two such sections $X, Y ∈ \operatorname{Γ}(Δ)$, we have $[X,Y] = Z$, where $Z ∈ \operatorname{Γ}(Δ)$ is also of the form above.

$$
[X, Y] = [δX^μ∂_μ -Γ^a{}_{μb}X^bδX^μ∂_a, \; δY^μ∂_μ -Γ^a{}_{μb}Y^bδY^μ∂_a] = \text{(mess)}
\tag{1}
$$

**Question:**
This route seems much messier to take.
Is computing the Lie bracket (1) the best way to show that $Δ$ is involutive? I can’t manage to put (mess) into a useful form.
How can I show $[X, Y] ∈ \operatorname{Γ}(Δ)$?

Cheers,